# How to enable pulse device to allow recording using portaudio

Tags: portaudio, pulse, pulseaudio

I'm currently working on a code to record voice bqsed on portaudio framework. For the moment, I can't make it works and I have the error code below.

```
0: /dev/dsp
An error occured while using the portaudio stream
Error number: -10000
Error message: PortAudio not initialized
```

I think that my issue is probably linked to a bad audio src which is not a pulse audio device. Is anyone can let me know how to setup a pulse device in order to allow port audio to access to it instead of /dev/dsp

Answer (score 0):

Did you call the function `Pa_Initialize()` before doing whatever else you were trying to do?